# Deploy Azure Stream Analytics Job for IoT Edge

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-rm-template, azure-iot-edge

I cannot deploy a Stream Analytics Job for IoT Edge automatically, since that I haven't find way to [specify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-stream-analytics#create-a-stream-analytics-job) **Edge** as **Hosted Environment**.
This property seems to be still not implemented in [ARM Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.streamanalytics/streamingjobs), [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.streamanalytics/New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsJob?view=azurermps-5.5.0&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-5.4.0) and Azure CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for this, we will add this in the documentation shortly
In the meantime you can use the following parameter: JobType="edge"
We'll add all the info in the doc.
Thanks,
JS

Comment: Hello JS, When trying to deploy my edge asa job (and having "jobType": "Edge" specified), I get the following error message : 
"Current operation is not supported for the API version and JobType 'Edge' specified in the client request".  Any idea or documentation on how to ARM-deploy an edge job ?

Comment: Hi, for ARM template you can use: "properties": { 
    "sku": {  
      "name": "standard" 
    }, 
      "eventsLateArrivalMaxDelayInSeconds": 1, 
      "jobType": "edge", 
    "inputs": […
  }
For the API, more info in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-cicd-api